# How do I restructure an API response?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, foreach, axios

Here is my back end route, is there something obvious that im missing when it comes to the returned data? I'm more experience with array manipulation, so when dealing with objects rather than forcing it into an array after returning data, how can I restructure this to return an array?

```
router.get('/caseDetail/:caseName', (req,res) => {
    db.caseDetail.findAll({
        
        include : [db.Part,db.Fault,db.Disposition,db.Contact,db.Site],
        where : {
            caseName:{ 
              [Op.like]: [req.params.caseName]}
        }
    }).then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
        res.json(response)
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
    })
})
```

Currently I'm returning an Object rather than an array of objects, **which is what im looking for**,
[image]
[image]

Comment: You'll need to show the shape of the returned data, and your expected refactor.

Comment: your not really returning anything at the moment ;) `return res.json(response)`

Comment: updated to include the response data, "return" function here is unneeded.

Comment: Can `findAll` be configured to return an array? If there is more than one result does an array come through to the client? What do you want the content of the output array to be?

Comment: Good questions @msbit, thats one of the underlying issues i've been trying to wrap my head around. I use a findOne method for a full read on the db and it shows all entries in an array with nested objects, however using findAll, its only returning one response of data, while this response is generated on user search of the term fenway, which there are two entries for in my db. Struggling to wrap my head around this.

Comment: If you are using Sequelize, it looks like `findAll` returns an array. Try using `console.log(JSON.stringify(response))` in your route instead of just `console.log(response)` to confirm that. Also, I note that your response (client or server, it's not clear) has all that under the `data` field. Do you have middleware somewhere in the Express stack that could be reformatting the output and possibly reducing the array down to a single value?

Comment: I finally figured out what was wrong, you had me thinking about the backend so I was comparing it to old APIs that ive written then I noticed on the front end, the route I was trying to hit had a syntax error, I changed ```let items = await axios.get(`/api/caseDetail/:${caseName}`);``` to ```let items = await axios.get(`/api/caseDetail/${caseName}`);``` and everything fell into place. Super happy about this, sometimes it helps to just talk it out with someone and im very thankful for your feedback.

Answer (score 1):

you forget to use `return` in `res.json(response)`

try `return res.json(response)`

Comment: `return` is unnecessary here, calling one of the methods on `res` (of which `json` is one) will send off the result.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here was a syntax error on my front end route,
After changing

```
let items = await axios.get(`/api/caseDetail/:${caseName}`);
```

to

```
let items = await axios.get(`/api/caseDetail/${caseName}`);
```

Everything fell into place and my use of [Op.like] worked like a charm. Thank you all for the help!